# Calling MySql Stored Procedure From C# - Exception "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, .net-core

I'm trying to call a stored procedure *add_membership* but the exception "*Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values*" is thrown. The exception is thrown during "*command.ExecuteNonQuery()*". My code is as follows and I will tell you what I've tried afterwards:

**Stored procedure**

```
CREATE DEFINER="doadmin"@"%" PROCEDURE "add_membership"(in id int, in memberEndDate datetime)
BEGIN
update public.members
    set
    deleted = 1 where public.members.userid = id and public.members.memberEndDate = memberEndDate and public.members.deleted = 0;

    insert into public.members(userId, memberEndDate) VALUES(id, memberEndDate);
END
```

**C# Stored Procedure Call**

```
public bool AddMembershipTime()
{
    try
    {
        using var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        using var command = new MySqlCommand("public.add_membership", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        command.Parameters["@id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberEndDate", DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30));
        command.Parameters["@memberEndDate"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**What I've Tried**
I know *id* is not null and *DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30)* is not null.
I've tried putting *DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30)* into MySql format (yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00).
Per other examples I found on the web I've tried making an array of parameters and using *Parameters.AddRange*.

Here is a screenshot of my database:

[image: Here is a screenshot of my database]

**Exception details**

```
ex.StackTrace:   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetFieldValue(Int32 index, Boolean checkNull)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.SchemaProvider.GetProcedures(String[] restrictions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.GetProcedures(String[] restrictions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.GetSchemaInternal(String collection, String[] restrictions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.SchemaProvider.GetSchema(String collection, String[] restrictions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.GetSchemaCollection(String collectionName, String[] restrictionValues)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.GetProcData(MySqlConnection connection, String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.AddNew(MySqlConnection connection, String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ProcedureCache.GetProcedure(MySqlConnection conn, String spName, String cacheKey)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.GetParameters(String procName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.CheckParameters(String spName)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.StoredProcedure.Resolve(Boolean preparing)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at  folder.User.AddMembershipTime() in C:\Users\folder\source\repos\folder\folder\User.cs:line 73
```

Thanks

Comment: Try to use Execute() instead of ExecuteScalar().

Comment: @Smits Thanks for the response. I just tried and MySqlCommand does not have a function Execute(). I've been using ExecuteNonQuery(). ExecuteScalar() was a mistype and I've edited the question.

Comment: @M W I have seen now that is actually ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @Smits Yes, sorry about that. I've tried ExecuteNonQuery(); Same exception.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I will get that to you within the hour, thanks.

Comment: I've already given you the full exception message and I edited my post with the stack trace @BradleyGrainger

Comment: @MW now that I see the call stack, I can see this problem has already been reported in the linked question. This is almost certainly a MySql.Data bug. You could try reporting it at bugs.mysql.com or switch to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Comment: Another possible workaround _might_ be to add `Check Parameters=false` to your connection string.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Thank you! Adding `Check Parameters=false` worked. Can you make an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: You can upvote the linked answer; I'll edit it to include this alternative.